# Recompile all packages after upgrading Go?

Tags: go

After I upgraded Go, how do I make sure all my packages in `$GOPATH/pkg` and binaries in `$GOPATH/bin` are recompiled using the new version ?

I would like that any upgrade errors are reported as warnings, not errors causing the operation to abort.

Comment: Manually, there is no help from the Go tool suite here.

Comment: @volker so it seam that I should erase the content of `bin` and `pkg` and call `go install all` ? I currently don't have any to try out. I'm installing a new host.

Comment: @scott that feels unsafe. I just want to recompile everything. The reason is that if I don't do that, I may see behavior that people using a clean compilation with the latest version don't see.

Comment: I just tried `go install all` on a fresh install with binaries and I get an error : `go install cmd/vendor/github.com/google/pprof: open /usr/local/go/bin/pprof: permission denied`. I had to untar as root in `/usr/local`. In `go help packages` it said that `all` is used to identify packages in the `$GOPATH`. This is confusing.

Comment: The `all` target rebuild some tools in GOROOT too. If you don't want to do that, then you just rebuild what you're interested in. If you want to make sure all _dependencies_ of a package are rebuilt, then use the install `-a` flag.

Comment: I would strongly advise against @ScottStensland's advice. There is absolutely no reason at all to delete source in this case, and the potential for losing changes in progress in various projects you may have checked out isn't worth the risk.

Comment: have you tried go build -a?, i remember that fixing your problem in previous go versions

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a single GOPATH path, you can update all packages by running this:

`cd $GOPATH/src
go get -u -v ./...`

If you have multiple GOPATHs you need to go into the `src` folder of each one of them and run:

`go get -u -v ./...`

Then run `go install all`